# Understanding JQUERY in RAILS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

For my project in RAILS I have to plot some data using Highstocks. That is why I am trying to understand the code.

In my index.html.erb I have this JS code:

```
<script >

    $(function () {
        var seriesOptions = [],
        /*Calling each action*/
        names = ['get_data_con','get_data_pro'],





      $.each(names, function(i,name){
        $.getJSON('/calculation/' + name, function (data) {


           alert(data)

        });
      });

    });

</script>
```

In my controller I have:

```
class CalculationController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end



  def get_data_con

    # Doing operations and rendering the data
        render json: data


  end

  def get_data_pro
        # Doing operations and rendering the data
        render json: data

  end


end
```

When I define `var seriesOptions = [],` it does not prompt the alert, but without this definition it does.

Why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: You have a trailing comma after your names array, it should be a semi-colon.

Comment: And you should pay attention to your JavaScript console.

Comment: Solved, thanks. But when should be comma or semi colon?

Comment: @kaka I'd consider spinning through essentially any JavaScript tutorial. http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript discusses semicolons in detail.

Comment: Javascript remain same in any framework, semi colon will be the ending of statement.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice @DaveNewton

Comment: End of an javascript statement you should use semi-colon(;), coma(,) should be used as an separator like passing parameter through a function calling, separating element in an array etc,